# Return type hints in Laravel. Good or bad idea?

Tags: php, laravel

I analyzed my Laravel project using phpstan (https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan). One of the most frequent complaints are concerning methods without return typehints, which I think are valid complaints. So I thought I'd start adding typehints to my controller methods (ie `public function index(): View` ). Most of them returns either Illuminate\View\View or Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse.

Questions:

1. Is this even a good idea? I think it generally makes things clearer, but return typehints aren't using anywhere in the Laravel documentation. Maybe it isn't good practice?
2. My big problem is some methods that return either or. Ie for example if the user is logged in they return a View, if not they return a RedirectResponse. How do I do return typehints for those methods?

Comment: Although I like the question, it's nothing but opinion-based. You either do it or you don't. Go with what makes you and your team happy.

Comment: Ok. Good point, @AlexKarshin. But my second questions still remains. How are return type hints done for a method that can return objects from different classes?

Comment: To answer your second question: you can either wait for PHP 8. Or you could create a new interface, say, `MySpecialReturnType`, then extend the View with an empty class and the RedirectResponse with an empty class and implement your interface on both. Then you may typehint `MySpecialReturnType` on return. Ah yeah, and return your _extended_ classes in the method body. Should work.

Comment: @AlexKarshin from the first comment you wrote one could understand that type hinting is more about readability, but in fact, its applicability is more about making the application more robust and less prone to bugs. In my opinion, we must always try to use type-hinting, whether the team is happy about it or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I second [@Alex Karshin comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61729377/return-type-hints-in-laravel-good-or-bad-idea#comment109189040_61729377).

Taylor Otwell [stated his opinion](https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/1409) clear in a [proposal](https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/1409) to type hint everything that could be type hinted.

I personally like to use type hints anywhere possible, like for defining properties or arguments for methods and functions or as return types. Spatie or BeyondCode for example uses them too.

Currently, PHP does not allow union type hints, but [will be](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/union_types_v2) in PHP 8. Until it's release you can use DocBlocks for that matter:

```
/**
 * @var string|int
 */
protected $property;
```